# Creating Async request execution in fire and forget fashion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to implement file upload to cloud with a kind of fire and forget mechanism. But would just be interested in some other action once all files are processed (success/failure doesn't make a difference).

```
public async void OuterMethodAsync(List<BlobFile> files)
{
    List<Task> uploadTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach(var uploadFile in files)
    {
        Task uploadTask = UploadToCloudAsync();
        uploadTasks.Add(uploadTask);
    }

    //Some sync logic unrelated to above tasks

    //awaiter
    Debug.WriteLine("Before Await");
    await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);
    Debug.WriteLine("After Await");

    SomeOtherSyncMethodPostAwait();
}

public async Task UploadToCloudAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Before Upload");
    //Upload to blob logic
    Debug.WriteLine("After Upload");
}
```

In this case, for a 3 file scenario, I was expecting that I would be seeing something like,
1. Before Upload 1
2. Before Upload 2
3. After Upload 1
4. Before Upload 3
5. Before Await
6. After Await 2 (or 3 whichever is faster)
7. After await 3 (or 2 whichever is slower)
8. After Await

But all my calls are being logged synchronously. I have tried combination of big and small files where timestamp does show a difference of 2 seconds or so. Is my implementation of async correct?

Also caller of my OutMethodAsync does not await for this method to be returned. In which case it should be running like a fire and forget? But considering internally it is running in sync my asumption is awaiter or not, OuterMethodAsync will also actually be a synchronous one?

Comment: Does your real `UploadToCloudAsync` actually have an `await`? The code as-posted will run synchronously because `UploadToCloudAsync` is synchronous (and there is a compiler warning stating this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One key thing to note here, async != new thread.

Your synchronization context dominates which thread the async method will execute on and if it will use a new thread for it.

If you want predictable parallel execution then you can do `Task.Run` to run the task on a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't disclose the runtime, I'll assume one with a `SynchronizationContext`.

With a synchronization context, the continuations will always be posted to it serializing those continuations.

To avoid that, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all `await`'s that should not continue on the synchronization context.